# Can I use TimeMachine only when on wired connection?

Tags: network, time-machine, backup

I have a server to which I am backing up a single MacBook Pro running Mountain Lion, via TimeMachine.

I would like to only back up when the MacBook Pro has a wired connection to the network. The wired and wireless connections are to the same router and all devices are on the same subnet.

**How can I configure my Mac so that it will not start the TimeMachine backup process when operating wirelessly, but will allow backups when connected via wired connection?**

The only idea I have had is manually disable TimeMachine when operating wirelessly. I see the TimeMachine has an option to not back up when on battery power, but it is possible that the laptop is plugged in to power, but not to wired ethernet.

Comment: Given that solutions to this may be fairly convoluted, it's worth drilling down to the underlying question: why is it necessary to prevent the Mac from backing up over WiFi?

Comment: @DanJ I have a suspicion that WiFi backup is causing issues with reliability of backup, but have not been able to show conclusively. (I have had this problem: http://pondini.org/TM/C13.html)

Comment: Josh - I have a "non-answer" which is to use the networking to isolate the share and only provide it to the wired connections. On AirPort hardware this is accomplished by having clients connect to the "Guest" network and allow them to all talk to themselves. This places the WiFi clients in a VLAN separate from the Time Capsule drive. With any enterprise routers and switches, you can do the same - place shares or printers or other resources in a protected status to control access. Sadly there isn't a similar "don't backup on battery or WiFi" toggle you can engage to make this easier.

Answer (score 2):

I use this: https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/26341/timemachinescheduler

Solved all of my TM and corrupt sparse bundle issues (backing up to a Synology NAS)

Comment: Answers on AskDifferent should be more than just a link. It's ok to include a link for downloads etc., but please add some details about what the software does and how it solves the problem described in the question.

Comment: I've used this as well. It did solve my corrupt sparse bundle issues. Unfortunately, it seems to get stuck on occasion. Once every few months, I'll notice it hasn't backed up for a week or more, even though my laptop has been regularly connected via ethernet. I think the intermitted issues started when I upgrade to Mountain Lion and v 4.0b8 of TimeMachinScheduler.

Answer (score 1):

[ControlPlane](http://www.controlplaneapp.com) includes an action:

- Toggle Time Machine